# ERROR: (gcloud.run.deploy) spec.template.spec.containers[0].image: Must provide an image URL to deploy

Tags: deployment, google-cloud-run, building-github-actions

I am using `Github Actions` to push an image into `GCP Artifact Registry` and later deploy to `Cloud Run`

All the process goes fine, except the automatic deploying to `Cloud Run`.

Below is the link for the example that guided me

https://github.com/codeedu/live-imersao-fullcycle10-nestjs-tests/blob/main/.github/workflows/ci_cd.yml

The error is as below:

```
Deploying...
failed
Deployment failed
ERROR: (gcloud.run.deploy) spec.template.spec.containers[0].image: Must provide an image URL to deploy
```

I appreciate any help to accomplish this task

Below is the workflow file:

```
name: CI and CD

on:
  workflow_dispatch:
  push:
    branches: [main, develop]

env:
  REGISTRY: gcr.io
  IMAGE_NAME: ${{ secrets.GCP_PROJECT_NAME }}/${{ secrets.CLOUD_RUN_SERVICE }}
  REGION: us-central1
  # REGISTRY_GIT: ghcr.io
  # IMAGE_NAME_GIT: ${{ github.repository }}

jobs:
  test-code:
    runs-on: ubuntu-20.04

    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v3
    - name: Use Node.js 16.x
      uses: actions/setup-node@v3
      with:
        node-version: 16.x
    - run: npm ci
    - run: npm run test
  
  build-image:
    needs: test-code
    if: github.ref == 'refs/heads/main'
    runs-on: ubuntu-20.04
    outputs:
      tags: ${{ steps.meta.outputs.tags }}
    concurrency: build-image-process
    steps:
      - name: Checkout repository
        uses: actions/checkout@v3

      # Workaround: https://github.com/docker/build-push-action/issues/461
      - name: Setup Docker buildx
        uses: docker/setup-buildx-action@79abd3f86f79a9d68a23c75a09a9a85889262adf
      
      # Login against a Docker registry except on PR
      # https://github.com/docker/login-action
      - name: Log into registry ${{ env.REGISTRY }}
        if: github.event_name != 'pull_request'
        uses: docker/login-action@28218f9b04b4f3f62068d7b6ce6ca5b26e35336c
        with:
          registry: ${{ env.REGISTRY }}
          username: _json_key
          #username: ${{ github.actor }}
          password: ${{ secrets.GCP_SERVICE_ACCOUNT }}
          #password: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}

      # Extract metadata (tags, labels) for Docker
      # https://github.com/docker/metadata-action
      - name: Extract Docker metadata
        id: meta
        uses: docker/metadata-action@98669ae865ea3cffbcbaa878cf57c20bbf1c6c38
        with:
          images: ${{ env.REGISTRY }}/${{ env.IMAGE_NAME }}
      
      # Build and push Docker image with Buildx (don't push on PR)
      # https://github.com/docker/build-push-action
      - name: Build and push Docker image
        id: build-and-push
        uses: docker/build-push-action@ac9327eae2b366085ac7f6a2d02df8aa8ead720a
        if: ${{ github.event_name != 'pull_request' }}
        with:
          context: .
          file: ./Dockerfile.prod
          push: true
          tags: ${{ steps.meta.outputs.tags }}
          labels: ${{ steps.meta.outputs.labels }}
          cache-from: type=gha
          cache-to: type=gha,mode=max
        
      - name: Outputs tags
        run: echo "${{ steps.meta.outputs.tags }}"

  deploy-image:
    needs: build-image
    if: github.ref == 'refs/heads/main'
    runs-on: ubuntu-20.04

    steps:

      - name: Checkout repository
        uses: actions/checkout@v3
    
      - id: 'auth'
        uses: 'google-github-actions/auth@v0'
        with:
          credentials_json: '${{ secrets.GCP_SERVICE_ACCOUNT }}'
    
      - name: 'Deploy to Cloud Run'
        uses: 'google-github-actions/deploy-cloudrun@v0'
        with:
          service: ${{ secrets.CLOUD_RUN_SERVICE }}
          image: ${{ needs.build-image.outputs.tags }}
          region: ${{ env.REGION }}
```

Comment: Are you still facing issue? If so can you share the document or tutorial you followed to deploy automatically?

Comment: My solution was to hard code the image name. After some executions, the command `steps.meta.outputs.tags` started showing the correct image name.

Comment: Can you share your solution as answer so that it will help others also?

Comment: I am still waiting for a proper answer. I just did a workaround to make it work. Image name hard coded `image: "gcr.io/projectName/cloudRunName:main"`

Comment: The command `needs.build-image.outputs.tags` is still empty and that's why I hard coded the image name.